# not able to submit the ajax form after replaceWith

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to learn to create a shopping cart this is my cart jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ajaxform").submit(function(e) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "cart.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $(".cartrow").append("<div class=\"cart-row\">" + responseData + "</div>");
            },
            error: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //if fails 
                alert("fail");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
    });

});
```

this is the html form I am using to submit the form

```
  <div class="product-tab" ID="disp"> <!-- bootstrap - min -->
                    <div class="product-detail fade active in " id="all" > <!-- bootstrap - min -->
                    <form class="ajaxform" method="post" ><h4><input type="hidden" name="pid[]"  value="1001">
                        <input type="hidden" name="unit"  value="10">onion(<del>&#2352;</del> 120)<hr></hr></h4>10<br><h6>
                        <label class="group"><input type="number" maxlength="2" name="quantity"/></label><h6>
                        <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" class="btn"></input><hr></hr></form>
                        </div>
            </div>
```

when I submit the form it works fine , I am able to add items to my cart but when I try to filter my items using the code below the add to cart button wont call my jquery for adding items to cart

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
         var selectedPrice = new Array();
         $('input[name="price"]:checked').each(function() {
             selectedPrice.push(this.value);
         });
         var brand = new Array();
         $('input[name="filter[]"]:checked').each(function() {
             brand.push(this.value);
         });

         $.ajax({
             url: 'no_product_filter.php',
             type: 'post',
             data: {
                 selectedPrice: selectedPrice,
                 brand: brand
             },
             success: function(response) {

                 $("#disp").replaceWith("<div class=\"product-tab\" id=\"disp\">" + response + "</div>");


             },
             error: function(response) {
                 alert("fail" + response);
             }
         });
     });
 });
```

is there something I should no when using jquery replaceWith .The response mentioned above which I get from my php has the same structure as my html barring items which I removed using my filter . please have a look

Comment: Due to dynamically created `<form>`, use `$(document).on("submit", ".ajaxform", function(e)`

Comment: Moreover, I don't see any reasons to replace `#disp` with `#disp`. You can simply write `$("#disp").html(response);` Then `#disp` will be a static element on page, and event handler could be improved into `$("#disp").on("submit", ".ajaxform", function(e)`